# How do I get the ratio when only given 3 sums of a geometric sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

The exercise:

> The sum of the first four terms of a geometric progression is $520$. The sum of the first five terms is $844$. The sum of the first six terms is $1330$. Find the common ratio of the geometric progression.

I have done

$$\frac{a(1-r^4)}{1-r} + ar^{(5-1)} =  \frac{a(1-r^5)}{r-1}$$

$$1-r(a(1-r^4)+ar^4) = 1-r(a(1-r^5)$$

$$1-r(a-ar^4+ar^4) =  1-r(a-ar^5)$$

$$1-r(a) = 1-r(a-ar^5)$$

$$a-ar = 1-r(a-ar^5)$$

$$a-ar = a-ar^5-ar+ar^6$$

and thats it, I don't know what to do, if I did something wrong or anything.

Comment: Please do not use pictures of symbols for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched, and are not viewable to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Comment: HINT…since you are given the numerical value of the sum of the first $4$ terms and the sum of the first $5$ terms you can easily deduce the value of the fifth term. Likewise with the sixth term…